# Finding which table row has the selected class so that it can be deleted

Tags: jquery, html

I have this:

```
$("tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e) {     
  $(this)
     .toggleClass("selected")
     .siblings(".selected")
         .removeClass("selected");
});
```

which allows me to select a specific row and assign it the "selected" class. The user now has the option to click a delete button on the bottom of the table to delete this row that he's selected. I was thinking of, when the user clicks the delete button, iterate through all of the table rows and delete the one with the selected tag, but I'm not sure how to do this. Is there a better way or can someone explain how this is done?

Comment: No, the better way is to attach a click handler to the delete button itself than navigate to the row and remove it. Can you provide some HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any HTML, I'm creating my own table.

CSS background color to see table row with 'selected' class

```
<style>
.selected{
background-color:#dddddd;
}
</style>
```

Generic table and button

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Sunday</td>
<td>01</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Monday</td>
<td>02</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tuesday</td>
<td>03</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button id="deleteRow">Delete Row</button>
```

JQuery to add class and remove table rows

```
$(function() {

$(document).off('click', 'tbody tr').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        $this.removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $this.addClass('selected');
    }
});

$(document).off('click', '#deleteRow').on('click', '#deleteRow', function() {
    $('tbody tr.selected').remove();
});

});
```